# When a matrix is diagonalized as $A = P^{-1}DP$, must $P$ consists of eigenvectors of $A$?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

A matrix $A$ is diagonalizable when it can be expressed as P^{-1}DP. I know that $D$ must consists of eigenvalues of $A$. However, I am not sure if $P$ must consists of eigenvectors of $A$. Is it a must for $P$ to consists of eigenvectors of $A$? It seems to be that it is not a must. However, I cannot prove it.

So the question is when a matrix is diagonalized as $A = P^{-1}DP$, must $P$ consists of eigenvectors of $A$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $PA=DP$, or if $P_{i}$ is the $i^{th}$ column of $P$ and $d_i$, the $i^{th}$ diagonal element of $D$, then $AP_i=d_iP_i$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, $P^{-1}$ must consist of eigenvectors of A, not $P$. Each column of $P^{-1}$ is an eigenvector of $A$:
$$
P^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix} e_1& e_2& \ldots& e_n\end{bmatrix}
$$
To prove this, we can multiply the equality $A=P^{-1}DP$ by $P^{-1}$:
$$
AP^{-1}=P^{-1}D
$$
or
$$
A\begin{bmatrix} e_1& e_2& \ldots& e_n\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} e_1& e_2& \ldots& e_n\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1&0&\ldots&0\\
0&\lambda_2&\ldots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&\ldots&\lambda_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which expands to
$$
Ae_1=\lambda_1 e_1,\;
Ae_2=\lambda_2 e_2,\;\ldots\;,\;
Ae_n=\lambda_n e_n.
$$